# Metamask requests not responding on mobile

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I have a webapp using web3/ matamask and calling the following:

```
 await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
```

and

```
 await window.ethereum.request({
   method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
   params: [{ chainId: chainId }], 
 });
```

All working well on desktop but nothing happening on mobile even though I do have metamask installed.

Are we supposed to do something special to communicate with metamask on mobile?